# Can we use of the Metropolis-Hastings importance sampling estimator here?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, measure-theory

> **EDIT**: Note that proposing according to $\hat Q$ is equivalent to the following scheme: Given the current state $\tilde x=(i,x')\in\tilde E:=I\times E'$ and $x:=\varphi_i(x')$, sample $j\sim\tilde T(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;)$. Now perturb $z':=\varphi_j^{-1}(x)$ to $y'\sim U'(z',\;\cdot\;)$ and finally propose $(j,y')$.
>
> Intuitively, by the construction of $\tilde T$, shouldn't $w_i(x)>0$ imply $w_j(x)>0$? I mean, we essentially sample $j$ with probability $w_j(x)$ and if $w_i(x)>0$ we should expect that $w_j(x)\ge w_i(x)>0$. However, I fail to see how this can be made rigorous.

I want to use the importance sampling estimator described in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf) in the following scenario, but struggle to show asymptotic unbiasedness (Theorem 14 in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf)) since the sufficient assumption 1 in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf) doesn't hold in my setting. Can we fix this by modifying the estimator in a suitable sense?

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $I$ be a finite nonempty set
- $p,q_i$ be probability densities on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ for $i\in I$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $w_i:E\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable for $i\in I$

Assume $$\{p=0\}\subseteq\{q_i=0\}\subseteq\{w_i=0\}\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in I\tag1$$ and $$\bigcup_{i\in I}\{q_i>0\}=\{p>0\}\subseteq\left\{\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1\right\}\tag2.$$ Now let

- $(E',\mathcal E',\lambda')$ be a measure space
- $\varphi_i:E'\to E$ be bijective and $(E',\mathcal E)$-measurable with $$\lambda'\circ\varphi_i^{-1}=q_i\lambda\tag3$$ for $i\in I$
- $\zeta$ denote the counting measure on $(I,2^I)$
- $$\tilde t((i,x'),j):=\left.\begin{cases}\left(w_j\circ\varphi_i\right)(x')&\text{, if }(p\circ\varphi_i)(x')>0\\|I|^{-1}&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}$$ for $(i,x')\in\tilde E$ and $j\in I$ and $$\tilde T(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;):=\tilde t(\tilde x,\;\cdot\;)\zeta\;\;\;\text{for }\tilde x\in\tilde E$$
- $u':E'\times E'\to(0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E'\otimes\mathcal E'$-measurable with $$\int\lambda'({\rm d}y')u'(x',y')=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x'\in E'\tag4$$ and $$U'(x',\;\cdot\;):=u'(x',\;\cdot\;)\lambda'\;\;\;\text{for }x'\in E'$$
- $\hat Q$ denote the transition kernel with density $$\hat q((i,x),(j,y)):=q_j(y)\tilde t\left(\left(i,\varphi_i^{-1}(x)\right),j\right)u'\left(\varphi_j^{-1}(x),\varphi_j^{-1}(y)\right)$$ for $(i,x),(j,y)\in\hat E:=I\times E$ with respect to $\hat\lambda:=\zeta\otimes\lambda$
- $\hat\mu$ denote the measure with density $$\hat p(i,x):=w_i(x)p(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(i,x)\in\hat E$$ with respect to $\hat\lambda$

> I'm running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target distribution $\hat\mu$ and proposal kernel $\hat Q$. In the notation of the paper, I've chosen $(G,\mathcal G,\mu)=(I\times E,2^I\otimes\mathcal E,\zeta\otimes\lambda)$, $\rho=\hat p$ and $p=\hat q$. The function $\overline\rho$ defined in equation 5 of [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf) is here given by \begin{equation}\begin{split}\hat\rho((i,x),(j,y))&:=\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{\hat p(j,y)}{\hat q((i,x),(j,y))}&\text{, if }\hat q((i,x),(j,y))>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\end{split}\tag5\end{equation} for $(i,x),(j,y)\in I\times E$.

While the state space of the chain is $I\times E$, I only want to estimate $\mathcal E$-measurable $g:E\to[0,\infty)$ with $$\{p=0\}\subseteq\{g=0\}\tag6.$$ (Note that any such $g$ can be considered as a functon on $I\times E$ by mapping $I\times E\ni(i,x)\mapsto g(x)$ and noting that the $\hat\mu$-integral of this function is $\sum_{i\in I}\int w_ig\:{\rm d}\mu=\mu g$).

The problematic thing is that assumption 1 in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf) is not satisfied (since $\hat p(\hat y)>0$ does not imply $\hat q(\hat x,\hat y)>0$ for all $\hat x$) and so asymptotic unbiasedness doesn't seem to hold, since \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\int\hat\mu({\rm d}(i,x))\int\hat Q((i,x),{\rm d}(j,y))\hat\rho((i,x),(j,y))g(y)\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=\sum_{j\in I}\left(\int w_j\:{\rm d}\mu\right)\int_{\{\:q_j\:>\:0\:\}}g\:{\rm d}\mu\end{split}\tag7\end{equation} and this expression doesn't seem to be equal to $\mu g$ (if I'm not missing something).

> Can we fix this? Maybe by modifying the estimator (equation 6 in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf)) in a suitable way such that we don't deal with $(7)$ in the proof of Theorem 14 in [(1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf)?

**EDIT 2**: Feel free to assume that $I\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $$q_{s'}(x)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }s'\in\{s,\ldots,s''\}\tag8$$ whenever $x\in E$ and $s,s''\in I$ with $s\le s''$ and $q_s(x)q_{s''}(x)>0$.